# Equals sign gets appended to the end of URL (interferes w/ Base64 value)

Tags: angular, typescript, url, base64, angular-ui-router

I have a URL that's partially Base64 encoded:

`http://localhost:4200/something/xyz?c291cmNlSWQ9MTIzNDUmc291cmNlVHlwZT1UJmNsaWVudE5hbWU9V2F5c3RhciUyMFJveWNvJmZpcnN0TmFtZT1Ub20mbGFzdE5hbWU9V2FtYnNnYW5zJmVtYWlsQWRkcmVzcz10d2FtYnNnYW5zQHdheXN0YXIub3Jn`

decoded -->

`http://localhost:4200/something/xyz?sourceId=12345&sourceType=T&clientName=Waystar%20Royco&firstName=Tom&lastName=Wambsgans&emailAddress=twambsgans@waystar.org`

The URL params are then assigned to variables and pre-filled into an onscreen form.

When I navigate to that link, however, an `=` is appended to the end of it, and I believe it's the reason why the code is not behaving as intended (not pre-filling).

---

If I could, I'd chop off the last character if it's an `=` but the *problem* is that some URLs with similar params (i.e. `firstName=Greg`) need to have the `=` on the end because that's how they're Base64 encoded.

So my question is, why is the `=` getting appended? Is there something I need to do codewise to prevent it from happening? Thanks very much.

---

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {

decodedUrlString: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserInfo();
  }

  getUserInfo() {
    let encodedUrlStub = window.location.search.substring(1);
    const b64Validator = new RegExp(/^([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{4})*(([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{2}==)|([0-9a-zA-Z+/]{3}=))?$/);

    let encodedString$ = of(encodedUrlStub);

    encodedString$.subscribe((val: string) => {
      if(b64Validator.test(val)) {
        console.log('is b64');

        this.decodedUrlString = this.decodeStr(val);
        console.log(this.decodedUrlString)
  
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(this.decodedUrlString);
  
        // params are assigned to variables here
  
        this.prefillForm(params);
        
      } else {
        console.log(`this ain't b64`)
      }
    }),
    error => console.log(error);

    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

  decodeStr(str: string): string {
    return decodeURIComponent(window.atob(str));
  }

}
```

---

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ay2tud?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

[image showing that the = was added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tm2VB.png)

[bookmarked link where I did not add the =](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCEMN.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I quite understand your problem but it appears that the only reason you're dealing with this mess is because you want to prefill the form based off of the url params? If this is correct there is a much easier way. You can use the `ActivatedRoute` to get the params. This would look like:

```js
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.prefillForm(params);
    });
  }

}
```

[Reference the docs](https://angular.io/guide/router#getting-route-information)

Comment: Since the URL's supposed to be coming in as Base64 encoded, I have to go through the process of decoding it. So unfortunately, I won't be able to do `this.route.queryParams`.

Comment: @Bodrov For that, the browser automatically adds an equals sign to any query parameter that doesn't have an equals because that's spec. The best solution with the current way you are being sent the data (that I can think of) would be to try decoding both ways. if one fails then the other is the correct one. I don't know enough about encoding to know how often this approach would fail but it could be checked if it was up to spec. Besides that it would require having control of the place generating the url and add an extra `=` followed by something that you would just chop off if you need Base64

Comment: Both ways being by subtracting the `=` and by keeping it